# Duplicate rows returned where in clause has repeated values

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Is this expected behaviour for Cassandra (2.0.3) / cqlsh (cql3.0.2)? 
Seems like a bug to me :

```
cqlsh> create table t1(c1 text primary key);
cqlsh> insert into t1(c1) values ('A');
cqlsh> select * from t1;

 c1
----
  A

cqlsh> select * from t1 where c1 = 'A';

 c1
----
  A

cqlsh> select * from t1 where c1 in( 'A');

 c1
----
  A

cqlsh:dslog> select * from t1 where c1 in( 'A','A');

 c1
----
  A
  A
```

???

Comment: If you'd like, could you open a bug here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA ?  If not, I'll open it myself in a few days.

Comment: Bug reported : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6706

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is a bug.  Internally, it appears the query engine generates two separate commands for this query and then combines the results without deduplicating.

It's interesting that there was a [very similar bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-2717) reported back in 2011, and it was fixed.  However, a new, completely rewritten version of the CQL query processor has been shipped in a later version of Cassandra, and I'm guessing this bug was again introduced.